# userDefaults saving level data as array not saving

Tags: swift, save

I have a game and I have custom levels which is saved as an array. I use the function saveCustomLevels to save the value of the level data. Every time the level data is changed, I do saveCustomLevels(). Whenever I do saveCustomLevels() and close the program and restart it the level data is always not saved and back to the default data. Am I doing something wrong. This is my code.

```
//in different class
func createLevels{
 customLevels = (0...8).map {_ in level}
}

//in regular class
func saveCustomLevels(){


    var customDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    customDefault.synchronize()


}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      var customDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        if customDefault.value(forKey: "Custom") != nil
            customLevels = customDefault.value(forKey: "Custom") as! Array<Array<square>>

        }

        square.createLevels()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    for touch in touches {



        let location = touch.location(in: self)
}

  if squares[i].node.contains(location){
      customLevels[zzz][s].startColor = colors[i]
           saveCustomLevels()
}
```

Comment: A breakpoint is a place in your code where the debugger will stop execution because you asked it to. Make sure you didn't add one accidentally. Do you get any error on the console when the execution stops? Also, your code seems incomplete. Where are you declaring `customLevels`? Please try adding more details to your question.

Comment: There is no breakpoint there, but I get no error.

Comment: i declare custom levels in another class but i know it has been declared because before i added saveCustomLevels i would change customLevels when making a custom level, so it would have to had already be added.

Comment: i found out why there was a breakpoint, i had tried to save with the key "Custom" twice, but now that i fixed i ran the project and changed part of the custom level, closed the program, opened it, and the level had reset the level data, so it must have never saved

Comment: Could you show us the code where you are assigning the level content to the "Custom" key of useDefaults.

Comment: sorry i don't really get what you mean

Comment: when i save the level using `saveCustomLevels()` i save it like `var customDefault = UserDefaults.standard;
    customDefault.synchronize()`

Comment: custom levels is an array of arrays of structs with SKSpritenodes, colors and integers. Would I have to save each one to UserDefaults? if i am saving the array that has all the arrays of structs, will it save all of the contents inside or will i have to save them manually?